# What exactly does happen by means or URL encoding and URL decoding while dealing with cookies in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, urlencode, setcookie, urldecode

I'm learning the concept of **Cookies** in PHP from [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp)

Till now I've understood that

**A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.**

I studied the following demo program present at the above link location :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
  $cookie_name = "user";
  $cookie_value = "John Doe";
  setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
<html>
  <body>

  <?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
      echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
    } else {
      echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
      echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }
  ?>

  <p><strong>Note:</strong> You might have to reload the page to see the value of the cookie.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

After going through the above code few questions have raised in my mind. I want satisfactory answers for them.

1. As cookie is nothing but a file that server embeds on the user's computer then where is the file creation and manipulation code? Without file manipulation and file uploading code how does the server embed file on user's computer or how does the browser send request to the server along with the cookie file?
2. Although, if I believe that the cookie file has been embedded by the server on user's computer then where is the file located on my machine that runs on Windows 10 Home Edition?

I also read one statement as below :

**Note:** The value of the cookie is automatically URLencoded when sending the cookie, and automatically decoded when received (to prevent URLencoding, use setrawcookie() instead).

Let me frankly tell you I didn't get at all what this sentence mean and what exactly does happen while sending and receiving cookies. I also don't know what is URL encoding and URL decoding in PHP?

It would be better if someone clears all of my above doubts with good explanatory answer and working code example.

Let me tell you honestly that as I heard from experienced PHP developers that Cookies and Session are the most important, basic concepts in PHP. But, I'm finding them difficult to understand. So, please explain me in simple and lucid language that I could grasp these concepts in a better and easier manner.

In short I want to understand the concept, functioning and usage of cookies in PHP with the working code example.

Thank You.

Comment: 1. setcookie does that. 2. depends on browser and os

Comment: This tutorial teaches you wrong. A cookie is not a file. A cookie is just a piece of data (a string).

Answer (score 0):

*Storing and transporting cookies*

The tutorial is incorrect, or at least a bit confusing. Traditionally cookies were stored as separate files, but that is just an implementation detail, and it's completely up to the client, the browser, how a cookie is stored, if at all.

URL-encoding and -decoding is a way of encoding special characters that are not compatible with URLs in another sequence, for instance a space is converted into %20. This happens to make sure that the cookie reaches the other side well, and can be stored properly, but like the phrase about files, it is irrelevant for the *use* of cookies.

*So what is it for?*

The point of a cookie, is that it is a piece of information that is sent back and forth. When you call `setcookie`, that information (`$cookie_value`) is sent with the other content back to the client (say, the browser) that made the request. The client can store this information, and when it makes another request to the same server, it will send the cookie value along with the request.

That allows the server to use this value again and recognise that it's the same client that made the request.

A common use for cookies is to have *sessions*, where you can login and the site will remember who you are. In the simplest form (*BUT DON'T DO THIS*), the cookie value could contain the login information, so on every request you could verify that it is the same user again. Sending information like this is a bit unsafe though, because the information easily be read from the file and from the network traffic, so chances are great that you will leak private information Moreover, this won't allow you to distinguish between different sessions (when you log in on two different PC's, or on two different browsers).

A better and more common scenario, is where the user information is remembered on the server, for instance with help of the [`$_SESSION` variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). Instead of putting all the credentials in a cookie, a unique ID is generated that is linked to the session information. That [session id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) is stored in a cookie.

So, to use cookies,

- You *need* to know how to set a cookie and how to read it back.
- You'd *want* to know that it is stored in the browser and that it is sent back and forth with the requests and responses. (And how to check and reset its value in the browser, so you can verify and debug your code more easily).
- You *probably don't care* much about how the cookie is encoded, and how or where it is stored on disk. Those are implementation details that don't matter for general use.

*And to have* sessions, *you don't need to set cookies yourself at all!*

Because the need for sessions is so common, PHP has a complete implementation for storing session information and sending a cookie to remember the visitor. You don't even have to call `setcookie` yourself!

The best place to start is by reading up on [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and its related functions. Basically, if you call `session_start()` at the start of your script, you can then just manipulate the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable, and all the values in it will be stored inbetween request. The whole use of cookies, as well as the storing of session information on the server, is completely hidden by this little bit of PHP magic.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers use cookies to store information, yes, they are files, but are not downloaded/uploaded from/to server. The process is something like this:

- The browser connects to server and sends some data, including headers to identify the request (get, post, etc.) and sends cookies, if any exists.
- The server receives this headers and sends its own headers, to instruct the browser to redirect to another page, create cookies or simply specify the content type that will be send next.
- Finally, the browser gets the content sent by the server and parse to render a page, download a file, or make a redirection to another URL.

  1. The browser is the one who write the cookie.
  2. As @rtfm said, the location of the cookies depends on browser and SO.